# Check if Matlab struct, dynamic Field Value is empty

Tags: matlab, struct, field, cell, is-empty

I have a struct *x*, with dynamic Fields, respectively dynamic Field names. But basically, only the **first Field** is relevant for me.
So I want to check if the Value of the **first Field** is empty, speak a *1x1cell* or a *0x1cell*..

[image]

or

[image]

I'm experimenting e.g. with:

```
isempty(fieldnames(x))
isempty(x(1))

if isempty(x(1))
    msgbox('empty')
else
    msgbox('result')
end
```

but got to no solution. Does anybody have a clue?

Speak, check if the Value of the **first** Field of the struct is empty or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the first field is relevant to you, then you can proceed as follows :

### Get the fieldnames list of your struct

```
names=fieldnames(x);
```

### Get the size of the first field

```
SizeOfFirstField=size(x.(names{1}));
```

Then you can just check if the first value in `SizeOfFirstField` is 0 or 1 in your `if` condition :

```
if SizeOfFirstField(1)==0
    msgbox('empty')
else
    msgbox('result')
end
```

Comment: I would probably use `if ~numel(x.(names{1}))` or `if isempty(x.(names{1}))` rather than checking the first element of size like that because this would fail if `x.(names{1}) = zeros(2,0)` @florian.isopp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also try this shorter form:

```
isempty(fieldnames(x))
```

where *x* is your struct variable.